# Microbit Platformio development - 'PlatformIOLibBuilder' object has no attribute 'get_inc_dirs'

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed, bbc-microbit, platformio

I am currently trying to play around with developing on a BBC microbit on c++ through the Platformio IDE on Atom.

I have got the software working with other boards (various NUCLEO boards that I own), and the code itself for the mircobit is the simple "Hello World" scroller that compiles fine on the mbed online compiler.

When compiling on platformio I get:

```
Attribute Error: 'PlatformIOLibBuilder' object has no attribute 'get_inc_dirs'
```

I have tried installing the microbit University of Lancaster libraries, and platformio says they are installed but it doesn't appear in the lib folder of the project I am using.

When it comes to developing I am very much a newbie in terms of setting up environments and IDEs, and I keep searching everywhere for answers on this but its hard to filter out what I need to do to fix this issue. While the microbit is a supported board, there is no guide as to how to get started with it, and every other board just seems to work fine with all the default installations.

UPDATE: The solution below works also for Ubuntu and windows though LED displays come out a bit garbled when you try and scroll text. However, serial communication shows that the actual microbit is doing what it should.

The errors in the display may be down to the fact that the microbit libraries are v2.0.0-rc4 whereas the most up to date version of the University of Lancaster Libraries appear to be v2.0.0-rc10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
I am using Linux Mint and the platformio plugin in Atom. I had the reported error. First of all I used the command line tool to update platoformio:

```
~/.platformio/penv/bin/pio update
```

To remove the get_dirs error and enable my code to compile:

In

```
~/.platformio/lib/nrf51-sdk/platformio_extra.py
```

change line:

```
pio_lib_builder.env.Prepend(CPPPATH=pio_lib_builder.get_inc_dirs())
```

to:

`pio_lib_builder.env.Prepend(CPPPATH=pio_lib_builder.get_include_dirs())`

I got this idea from:

```
https://github.com/palfrey/nrf51-sdk/pull/1/files
```

To get my compiled code to load I run atom as sudo:

```
sudo atom
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have tried following the yotta instructions for both my Ubuntu and Windows partitions and run into errors. The ubuntu was having compiler issues and I am not very experienced with linux development. The windows attempt kept returning

    error: command ['ninja'] failed

which by the looks of things is an issue with the code more than anything else. The main reason I was asking about using it with platformio is that it appears to support the microbit board and have the libraries available to download so I am confused as to why i am getting this error.

Comment: I installed platformio and got some code to compile using the edited answer above. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thats great I have it working on Ubuntu (about to test for windows) and it is compiling fine now. I have noticed that the display functions are a bit off however (i.e. "hello World" just comes out as a load of random lit LEDs), but I imagine that this is a problem with the library itself since it was written to be compatible with yotta rather than the nordic compiler used by platformio for the microbit